# Python class NameError: global name not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use python class and below is the my first python class code:

```
import re
import time
import paramiko

hostname = "10.1.1.1"
net_username = "user"
net_password = "password"
class asr_qa:
    def __init__(self, hostname, net_username, net_password):

        ''' SSH connection Establish '''

        self.remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
            paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.remote_conn_pre.connect(hostname, username=net_username,
            password=net_password,look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
        self.remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
        buff = ''
        while not buff.endswith('#'):
            resp = remote_conn.recv(9999)
            buff += resp
            print(resp)

    def __disconnect__(self):
        self.remote.close()

    def __send_command__(self, cmd):
        remote_conn.send(self.cmd)
asr = asr_qa(hostname, net_username, net_password)
asr.__send_command__("ping 10.10.10.10\n")
print asr.resp
asr.__disconnect__()
```

I am getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    asr = asr_qa(hostname, net_username, net_password)
  File "test.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
NameError: global name 'remote_conn_pre' is not defined
```

Please let me know what i did wrong.

and also I tried to read many docs but i did not understand correctly what exactly `__init__` will do.

`__init__` is constructor of the class. when we call the class it initializes all the values under `__init__` (This special function gets called whenever a new object of that class is instantiated) and why cant we define `__init__` values directly to function itself?

what situation we should use `__init__`

Comment: As your error points out, you have not yet defined `remote_conn_pre` anywhere on that code, so your program doesnt recognize that token.

Comment: Does changing `self.remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()` to `self.remote_conn = self.remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()` change the error?

Comment: `remote_conn_pre` and `self.remote_conn_pre` are two different things

Comment: Don't use leading and trailing double underscores for your own methods!

Answer (score 0):

You defined self.remote_conn_pre, but later you called remote_conn_pre. remote_conn_pre is not the same as self.remote_conn_pre.

Change this:

```
self.remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
```

To this:

```
self.remote_conn = self.remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
```

You'll have to make similar changes elsewhere in your code, such as adding `self.` before `remote_conn.recv(9999)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forgot to put `self` in :

```
self.remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
```

Where it should have been:

```
self.remote_conn = self.remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
```